# Django Userena Customization

Tags: django

I have recently installed Django Userena on my Linux Apache server.

After correcting some errors, I began looking through the documentation. However, after searching through the docs and after many Google searches, I still cannot find out how to change the appearance of the pages! For example, how do I change the appearance of the signin page, the signup page, etc? I know that each userena template extends `base.html`, but where do I go from there?

I am probably missing something very simple, so please forgive me if the answer is very obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the `signin` method signature for Userena([source](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py#L285)) -

```
def signin(request, auth_form=AuthenticationForm,
       template_name='userena/signin_form.html',
       redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
       redirect_signin_function=signin_redirect, extra_context=None):
```

As you can see, there is a `template_name` method that holds the template location. You can override this. In your `urls.py`, you can use it like  -

```
url(r'^signin/', 'userena.views.signin', {'template_name': 'signin.html'}, name="signin"),
```

You can then create the `signin.html` page inside your `templates` folder and extend `base.html`. The `signin` view sends the login form in a variable called `form`. You can see [the source](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py#L359). You can use the form on your template `signin.html` like `{{ form.as_p }}`. You can also format each field individually if you can follow the `userena.forms. AuthenticationForm`. Again, check the [source code](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/forms.py#L142). You can do the same for any view Userena has that allows overriding like this.

When in doubt, read the source code. :)

Comment: Very thorough and helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `userena` *default* `templates`.

Create a directory inside your `templates/` named `userena/`, Then for example if you want to change `signup` form, easily create `signup_form.html` template file inside that `userena/` dir that you've just created and start writing.

For instance here is default [`signup_form.html`](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/templates/userena/signup_form.html) template.

You can find *userena* [default templates at its github repo](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/tree/master/userena/templates/userena)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the supplied userena templates in your template directory.

You can find them on a linux box with `find / -name userena`

The path you are looking for is `../userena/templates/userena`. Copy the userena folder into your template directory and start changing the `signin_form.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the templates to your own template directory. If you follow this [link](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/tree/master/userena/templates) download and just copy the directory 'userena' to your template directory. You can then customise the templates including the email text and templates.